# How to use trial and error

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the same problem as asked [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110868/45001)

In short, I am trying to find the values for which
$$8n^2 \lt 64n\,\log_2(n)$$

To find a solution in the real numbers, it involves using the Lambert W function, but as the domain of the functions is limited to the natural numbers [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110872/45001) suggests "do it numerically".

If this means plugging integers into the two functions and finding the values for which the inequality holds, **how should I approach the selection of the integers?**

How can I tackle this problem more efficiently than just picking numbers from the air?

Comment: Try it for few small numbers first, then try to prove it general 'n', or you can try induction! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify $$\tag08n^2<64n\log_2 n$$
to $$\tag1n<8\log_2 n.$$
As the logarithm has sublinear growst, there are at most finitely many $n$ that satisfy $(1)$.
More precisely, the derivative of the left hand side in $(1)$ is $1$, that of the right hand side is $ \frac{8}{n\ln 2}$. As this is $<1$ if $n>\frac 8{\ln 2}\approx11.5$ and $>1$ if $n<\frac8{\ln2}$, we expect that $(1)$ holds precisely for $n_1\le n\le n_2$ with integers $n_1<11.5$ and $n_2>11-5$ yet to be determined.

Finding $n_1$ is easy:
We see that $(0)$ is not satisfied for $n=0$ (right hand side not defined or $=0$, it's a matter of taste), $n=1$ ($8\not<0$), but is satisfied for $n=2$ ($32<128$). Hence $n_1=2$.

Now we look for $n_2$, which turns out to be a bit larger.
If we substitute $n=2^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb R_{\ge0}$, then $(1)$ becomes $2^\alpha<2^3\alpha$ or
$$\tag2 2^{\alpha-3}<\alpha.$$
This suggests to start trying at $\alpha=3$ where $(2)$ says $1<3$; next, $\alpha=4$ yields $2<4$ - still true; then $\alpha=5$ yields $4<5$ - still true; but the fourth try $\alpha=6$ yields $8\not<6$. So we should check for values of $n$ between $n=2^5=32$ (true) and $n=2^6=64$ (false), for example using binary search.
This lets us find (e.g. after testing $n=48$, $n=44$, $n=42$, $n=43$) that the upper limit for $n$ implied by $(0)$ is $n\le n_2=43$.

In summary:
$$ 8n^2<64n\log_2n\iff 2\le n\le 43.$$

Comment: By what principle do the derivatives imply that $n_1\le n\le n_2$? Could you perhaps elaborate on that step?

Answer (score 2):

Dividing through by $8n$ yields $n\lt8\log_2n$

Since $\log_2n$ is roughly the number of binary digits of $n$, this is fulfilled for small $n$ and not for large $n$. It seems easier to find the boundary if we transform to $n=2^k$, which yields $2^k\lt8k$. This is fulfilled for $k=5$ but not for $k=6$. Then binary search between $32$ and $64$ finds that $48$ is too high, $40$ is too low, $44$ is too high, $42$ is too low and $43$ is too low, so the inequality is satisfied up to and including $n=43$.

Alternatively, since $\log_2n$ changes slowly, start with some $n$ and iterate:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
n&\lceil8\log_2n\rceil\\\hline
2&8\\
8&24\\
24&37\\
37&42\\
42&44\\
44&44
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

After reducing the problem to the simplest form 
$$ \frac18n < \log_2n$$
I would plot the two functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=8\log_2x$ on the same plane (you may assume positive $x$ values, of course).
You observe that for $x<1$ the logarithm is negative and that the two functions are both monotonically increasing, but the logarithm grows slower. So there will be a limit value $x=x_0$ such that $f(x)>g(x)\quad \forall x>x_0$.

So you conclude that you are looking for a single interval of values (you may restrict yourself to the integers) between the two points of intersection of $f$ and $g$.

This for a reasonable qualitative analysis. Then you plug in specific values for $x$, or $n$. But not randomly!