# How do I solve $n <8 \log_2(n)$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am several years away from college so I've forgotten my math and I don't know how to solve this one. I've reviewed several logarithmic properties but I'm still stumped.

I am at this part:

move 8 to other side of equation:
$$\log_2 n < n/8$$

convert to exponential form:
$$2^{n/8} < n$$

Now what? anyone?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20652/how-to-solve-n-2n-8-for-n?rq=1

Comment: user63....you're using the wrong inequality